# How to publish quip live apps

Tags: quip, liveapps

In the dev console of a live app, there is a "Release Build" button. The instruction on the page also asks us to push the release build button when it's ready to publish. However that button is always greyed out. How can it be enabled?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug on Quip's side that will be resolved in the next few days. Sorry about that!

Comment: And now fixed! Sorry for the interruption; you shouldn't have any issue now.